# How to use parameters in SQL queries with the LIKE clause?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on a Windows Forms application and I have a problem with the parameters in my SQL string. I'm creating a searching system, where you can type  the name of the person or their first or last name. After, the results must be displayed in a label for each result found.

I made that, almost. The problem is that the query returns me **all** of the data in the database. Here is the code:

```
conexion.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
datos.Nombre = txtNomDoc.Text;
datos.APaterno = txtApellido.Text;
datos.AMaterno = datos.APaterno;

SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM MAESTROS WHERE " +
"Nombre LIKE @Nombre OR " +
"Paterno LIKE @Paterno OR " +
"Materno LIKE @Materno;", conexion);

teacherQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", "%" + datos.Nombre + "%");
teacherQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paterno", "%" + datos.APaterno + "%");
teacherQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Materno", "%" + datos.AMaterno + "%");

MessageBox.Show(datos.Nombre, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
MessageBox.Show(datos.APaterno, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
MessageBox.Show(datos.AMaterno, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(teacherQuery);
da.Fill(dt);

int noRows = dt.Rows.Count;
MessageBox.Show(noRows.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

for (int i = 0; i < noRows; i++)
{
    Label lblDocente = new Label();
    lblDocente.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Nombre"].ToString();
    flpResultados.Controls.Add(lblDocente);
}
```

I've searched the ways that I can put the parameters in the query. I tried do that in these ways and I got the same results:

```
SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM MAESTROS WHERE " + 
"(Nombre LIKE concat('%',@Nombre,'%')) OR " +
"(Paterno LIKE concat('%',@Paterno,'%'))  OR " +
"(Materno LIKE concat('%',@Materno,'%'));", conexion);

SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nombre FROM MAESTROS WHERE " +
"(Nombre LIKE '%' + @Nombre + '%' OR " +
"Paterno LIKE '%' + @Paterno + '%' OR " +
"Materno LIKE '%' + @Materno + '%');", conexion);
```

And, with this, I got the *dt.Rows.Count* like 0:

```
SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand("select Nombre from MAESTROS where " +
"(Nombre=@Nombre or " +
"Paterno=@Paterno or " +
"Materno=@Materno);", conexion);
```

In the *addWithValue* I tried with and without the *%*. I think the problem is with the *%* sign, because when I change the query by one static, that works. Also, if I remove the *%*, I got he results that I'm searching. In other case, Have I a problem with the SQL string?

Thank you, very much! Sorry if my English isn't too good.

Comment: We need to see a sample of your data and what values are passed in the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, guys. I tried the things that you suggest me, but I've found the solution:

```
SqlCommand teacherQuery = new SqlCommand( 
   "SELECT Numemp, Nombre " + 
   "FROM MAESTROS " +
   "WHERE (LEN(ISNULL(@Nombre,'')) = 0 OR Nombre LIKE ('%'+ @Nombre + '%')) " +
   "AND (LEN(ISNULL(@Apellido,'')) = 0 OR Paterno LIKE (@Apellido)) " +
   "OR (LEN(ISNULL(@Apellido,'')) = 0 OR Materno LIKE (@Apellido));", conexion);
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your dataset, but depending on the data and size a like clause can be incredibly ineffecient.  To correctly parameterize to your query, you could do the following.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @Sample+ '%'
```

The query is formatted to expect a wildcard search, as denoted the more complex and vague the query becomes, the dataset may produce undesired results.  Then you would simply do the following in code.

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sample", sample);
```

No formatting is required, because SQL already expects a wildcard search.  Often it is better to retrieve the dataset, cache the data, then search and filter off that in code.  Rather than produce complex dynamic like searches to the database, since SQL's performance stems from indexing of data columns in a relational manner.

Comment: '%@Sample%' does not work, you will get the literal text "%@Sample%" as the result. you have to do something like `LIKE `%` + @Sample + '%'`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Good catch, was in hurry.  Updated answer.

Comment: What about `Like @Sample` and `.AddWithValue("@Sample", "%" + sample + "%")`? :)

Comment: @ErikPhilips You could do that, but I find that explicitly defined query with wildcard is easier to diagnose and troubleshoot later on then hiding concatenated parameter values in the command.

Comment: IMHO finding '%' is not hard in either SQL nor C# code.  But, putting the % in the SQL and not the parameter makes the sql statement less usable.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Depends on the structure, I usually create resource files and have queries with names and functions that coincide with each other.  SearchForUserByName for instance or SearchOnAllFields.  Suppose it is a matter of preference.